# How to calculate all possible combinations of brackets order?

Tags: combinatorics, logic

**Hey**
I would like to find out a formula on calculating the maximum possible combinations of brackets order.

**First of all there a few rules:** 
- Brackets have to be valid (Every bracket has a closing bracket) 
- n % 2 == 0 (n = Brackets, only pairs) 
- The order is sensitive, e.g.: a,b and b,a equals 2 combinations

**What is a valid combination ?** 
Lets say n is our variable for the brackets count:

n = 2: () - Only 1 combination possible

n = 4 () (), (()) - Only 2 combinations possible

n = 6 ((())), () () (), (()()), (())(), ()(()) - 5 possible combinations

**Now any ideas how to calculate the combinations number when I only have n = ?**

*Greetings*

Comment: Catalan numbers?

Comment: Another duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529699/finding-the-formula-for-nth-catalan-number-as-total-number-of-combinations-of-ba)

Answer (score 3):

These are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_n=\frac 1{n+1}{2n \choose n}$  The second example in the Wikipedia article is this one.